# Is there a good graphical/pseudographical/web-based tool for managing Linux users and groups?

Tags: linux, user-management

Is there a good graphical/pseudographical/web-based tool for managing Linux users and groups?

To see them all at once, operate them (create, remove, associate (add/remove users to groups), modify) with couple of clicks?

Answer (score 6):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is generally considered to be pretty good at that and is probably already part of whatever distro you use.

If you look at their [screenshot page](http://www.webmin.com/demo.html), you can actually see some screenshots of creating and managing users.